# How to access fineuploader parameters onComplete function?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

```
   manualuploader.fineUploader('setParams', {
        foo: bar
      });

  var manualuploader = $('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    .
    .
    .

  })
  .on('submit', function(event, id, name) {
    .
    .

  }).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {

   // HOW CAN I ACCESS TO foo -parameter HERE?

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `responseJSON` parameter will include any and all keys and values returned in your server's response to the upload request.  The `setParams` function is used to send parameters in the upload request to your server.  If, for some reason, you want to make these same values available to your `complete` callback, simply include them in your server's response.